# Show Full SDO_DIM_ARRAY in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-spatial

In Oracle SQL Developer, when I run this query:

```
SELECT DIMINFO FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA;
```

I get results that look like this:

```
MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY([MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT],[MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT])
```

I don't want this collapsed version. I want the entire array printed out.

I'm pretty sure I did this about a week ago, but for the life of me, I cannot remember how.

Version: SQL Developer 3.2.20.09

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Preferences, Database, Advanced, try enabling the "Display Struct Data In Grid" option.  Does that help?

Comment: Sure does. I should mention that this could make geometries with large numbers of points a bit of a concern. I didn't have any trouble with a polygon with over 3,000 vertices, though, so what constitutes "large" is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer seems to be to join the array cast to the source table so that it expands each element of the array to a different row:

```
SELECT META.TABLE_NAME, META.COLUMN_NAME, META.SRID, DIM.*
FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA META, TABLE(META.DIMINFO) DIM;
```

The results look something like this:

```
TABLE_NAME    COLUMN_NAME    SRID    SDO_DIMNAME   SDO_LB      SDO_UB      SDO_TOLERANCE
TABLE1        GEOM           3857    X             -20037700   20037700    0.1
TABLE1        GEOM           3857    Y             -20037700   20037700    0.1
TABLE2        GEOM           3857    X             -20037700   20037700    0.1
TABLE2        GEOM           3857    Y             -20037700   20037700    0.1
```